# Unable to update

Tags: command-line, updates, update-manager

when i go into terminal and type in sudo apt-get update, the response is:
E: Malformed line 64 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: Type ‘

can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Edit file  /etc/apt/sources.list

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Got to line 64 and fix the error. If you can not find the error, comment the line.
A commented line starts with `#`.

The `deb` lines should look like

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ <dist> <section>`
```

Where

- dist : precise, utopic, ...
- section : universe, main, partner, ...

Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Comment: on line 64 it says 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/precise partner'

Comment: I would try to add `http://` and a `space` before `precise` `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, just do a backup of your existing "sources.list" available in the location : /etc/apt/

Steps to backup source.list,

```
1. Open the terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T

2. cd /etc/apt/

3. sudo cp source.list /etc/apt/source.list.bak 

4. sudo sed -i -e '64d' /etc/apt/sources.list (this deletes the problematic line)

5. sudo apt-get update (this updates the database)
```

hopefully this should fixes the issue - if not, please revert back the source file with the bak file we created in step 3.

Comment: after doing these steps E: Type ‘<!DOCTYPE’ is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read. appears on the screen and now when i try to type in a command my computer name appears with /etc/apt$ on the end